# True or false of real functions and their limits.

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist and $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x$ in some open interval $I$ containing $a$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$ doesn't exist either.

Any hint to this problem? I cannot seem to figure it out...

Comment: **HINT** Do you know a bounded function without limit?

Comment: This is false. Just draw $f(x)$ such that the left hand and right hand limit exist but aren't equal. And now draw a continuous function g(x) above $f(x)$ so $f(x)≤ g(x)$.

Comment: Claim is not true.

Comment: It is true if $\lim\limits_{x \to a } f(x) = +∞$, however.

Comment: I see. I think of $\tanh$ function. @TitoEliatron! Thank you for that insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $$f(x)= \sin (1/x)$$ and $g(x)=2$ on the interval $(-1,1)$

The limit of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ does not exist but $g(x)$ does have a limit.

Comment: Simple and great! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for   your attention